# URL Rewrite old URL to new URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite this:

```
index.php?action=dlattach;topic=2745.0;attach=14374;image
```

to this:

```
attachments/opening-inauguracion-png.14374/
```

What I've built so far but it isn't working is this:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php?=dlattach;topic=([0-9]+);attach=([0-9]+);image /attachments/$2/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To manipulate the query string you need to use a rewrite condition with `%{QUERY_STRING}`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attach=([0-9]+) [NC]
# if you need a more exact match of your current query string
# comment the above RewriteCond and uncomment the below RewriteCond
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=dlattach;topic=[0-9\.]+;attach=([0-9]+);image$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ attachments/opening-inauguracion-png.%1/ [R=302,NC,L]
```

Also only change it to 301 once you have confirmed the rule is working to avoid caching your browser while testing a rule which can be bad in case the rule is not properly working to mitigate the same.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense and works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the opposite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^attachments/opening-inauguracion-png.([0-9]+)$ /index.php?action=dlattach;topic=2745.0;attach=$1;image [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Apparently not since it `seems` to be what he wants

Comment: Apparently.  It just seems odd to want to make the URL look like a messy parameter laden thing when it isn't.  Typically you see the opposite asked for, and I thought part of his problem was trying to go the other way on accident (i.e. had the two mixed up).  I'm kind of curious about the application of this.  In any case, my theory of error was wrong. I leave my answer in case someone is looking for the opposite.

Comment: He probably wanted to go from messy query string into a google usable URL.

Comment: But he's doing the opposite. He's going from a "cleaner" real file of: /attachments/opening-inauguracion-png.14374 by pointing the messy /index.php?action=dlattach;topic=2745.0;attach=14354;image at it.

Comment: Read his question carefully you're the one doing it the opposite. What you're doing on your rule is what you said above you're sending the clean one to the messy with a 301.

Comment: I'm simply redirecting old URLs to the new URLs of the new forum system we converted to, so we need to catch old URLS and move them to the new format so Google doesn't penalize us and stuff.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for satisfying my curiousity.